# Special characters on QNAP filesystem

Tags: windows, filesystems, mac, qnap

I installed and configured a QNAP TS-463U-RP in a branch office to mirror data used by this office and the main office.

Some time after the initial sync, I suddenly find special (maybe Unicode) characters in file- and directory names. Windows command line with the default codepage depicts them as a `?`, changing the codepage to e.g. 1252 shows the characters to be ``. Connecting via SSH shows them as `"`.

Now I *can* rename the files using SSH or the Windows command line (not using explorer, though), but this is tedious. I tried searching the directory structure using different tools (`find`, Windows Search, some 3rd party tools etc.) but couldn't come up with any pattern to automate the process.

My backup is up to date, except for the special-char-files which seem to be added at random, these I have to repair...

I don't even really **know** what characters these are.

I do know that they are using Macs on NTFS, maybe it has something to do with it.

So: How could I proceed in renaming the files automatically and - even more important - how could I prevent the files from being renamed / created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time tinkering with Unicode and Powershell I came across the module [Get-Unicodeinfo](https://powershell.org/2016/04/15/the-unicode-powershell-module/).
This module showed me that the filenames were created with the [special Unicode character](https://codepoints.net/U+F022?lang=en) `F020`.

So I wrote a oneline-script in Powershell:
`gci -recurse -Path Z:\ -Exclude Z:\Temp | where {$_.Name -match "[\uF022]"} | rename-item -newname {$_.name -replace "[\uF022]",""}`
to replace the Unicode characters with an empty string.

So far, so good, but I still don't know where the filenames came from. But till now, no new faulty files have been added. I presume, that some conversion from/to Mac/HFS+/NTFS/... played a part.